# Set custom Opportunity fields in convertLead()

Tags: opportunity, lead-conversion

I'm fairly new to Apex/Visualforce and I'm a bit stuck here. I have a custom Visualforce page and Apex controller for a Lead Convert button in which a new Opportunity is converted, and I'm trying to figure out how to set custom fields for that new Opportunity based on what's entered in the page. Basically, after this line:

```
leadConvert.setOpportunityName(myComponentController.opportunityID.Name);
```

I'd like to also set other fields and update that Opportunity (this line is in the convertLead() method). Is this possible to do from within the Controller, or do I need to create a trigger for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need information from the page state, your best bet would be to convert the lead, then update the opportunity in the page's controller afterwards. The [LeadConvertResult](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_database_leadconvertresult.htm) class gives you the Opportunity ID for the newly created record. Since the transaction will still be considered "in-flight", you are guaranteed to have the lock on this newly created opportunity until your controller method completes.